# NoneType object has no attribute count

Tags: string, list

I have problem with this 
it keeps saying: NoneType object has no attribute count

```
def failListiks(failinimi):
    with open(failinimi) as f:   
        listina = f.readlines()
        print(listina)
    return

minulist = failListiks("sonad.txt")
tahtedearv = minulist.count("a")
print(tahtedearv)
```

Answer (score 0):

`failListiks` is returning `None`. I suspect you want to return the list of lines, but you are merely printing them. See the following change:

```
def failListiks(failinimi):
    with open(failinimi) as f:   
        listina = f.readlines()
        print(listina)
        return listina # return the lines
```